# Search in list of strings by name of the string

Tags: c#

I have the following list I'm populating as I go through my class:

```
List<string> stringCollection = new List<string>();
```

I have a lot of static strings that I have declared before going to my class. 
These strings are added to my list based on a collection of conditional expressions, meaning that it varies what kind of strings that I put into my list e.g.:

```
static string DescriptionText1 = "blabla", 
              DescriptionText2 = "blabla", 
              MagnitudeText1 = "blabla",  
              MagnitudeText2 = "blabla"; 

if(number < 2)
{
    stringcollection.Add(DescriptionText1)
}
else
{
    stringcollection.Add(DescriptionText2)
}

//Magnitude

if(magnitude > 128 && number < 256)
{
    stringcollection.Add(MagnitudeText1)
}
else
{
    stringcollection.Add(MagnitudeText2)
}
...
```

I then pass the list to my method in which I want to retrieve the strings like so:

```
public void Collection(List<string> ts)
{
    string Description = ts.Find(DescriptionText); <--- my guess
    string Magnitude = ts.Find(MagnitudeText);
}
```

How do I find the correct strings in my list, and write it to my newly declared strings in my method? - Even though they are appended hence 1,2,3 ... 6,7

Comment: Seems like you either want a `Dictionary<string, string>` so you can index your strings with a name.  Or assuming you know what all the values are just create a custom class with string properties named for each of the types of text you have.

Comment: Oh, so what you suggest is that i go like `Dictionary<DescriptionText1, 1>` and for Magnitude: `Dictionary<MagnitudeText1, 2>` ? and then i would be able to search for my int variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you always put in `Description` first and then `Magnitude`, you can just do:

```
ts[0] // description
ts[1] // magnitude
```

Alternatively, consider writing a class that has the two properties:

```
// I don't know what these two things represent, please name it properly in your code!
class DescriptionMagnitude {
    public string Description { get; }
    public string Magnitude { get; }
    public DescriptionMagnitude(string description, string magnitude) {
        Description = description;
        Magnitude = magnitude;
    }
}
```

And then create an instance of this class and pass it around.

EDIT:

From your comment:

> and then i would be able to search for my int variable?

It seems like you want to find the integer associated with the string. However, the `1` in `DescriptionText1` is just part of an identifier. Why not just store the integer instead of the string?

Depending on what you are doing with the strings, an enum may be suitable:

```
enum Descriptions {
    Foo = 0,
    Bar = 1
    Fizz = 2
}
```

Comment: I guess I will do setters and getters in this case, didn't think this well enough through! Thank you for your time.